# Natural bijection between Dyck paths and tilting modules

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $A_n=kQ_n$ be the path algebra of linear oriented Dynkin graph $Q_n$ of Dynkin type $\mathcal{A_n}$ (so $A_n$ is the unique hereditary Nakayama algebra given by quiver and relations).

The number of tilting $A_n$-modules equals the Catalan numbers $C_n$ when $n$ is the number of simple $A_n$-modules.

> Question: Is there a natural bijection between Dyck paths of length $2n$ to the tilting modules of $A_n$?

I would think that this might be noted somewhere in the literature, but I did not find it.

Comment: The tilting modules correspond in a natural way to order ideals of the poset of positive roots, right? These order ideals are in obvious bijection with Dyck paths (because the poset is just a “triangle.”)

Comment: Maybe Chapter 3 here explains this?: https://arxiv.org/abs/1502.06553v2

Comment: @SamHopkins Thanks. Can you make this an answer with a little more detail? So given a Dyck path, what is the corresponding tilting module in the Auslander-Reiten quiver of the algebra(which can be described as a set of $n$ dimension vectors)? When I draw the Auslander-Reiten quiver of the algebra for $n=3$ and put in the 5 tilting modules in the triangle, I do not get immediately Dyck paths. So Im note sure what the natural bijection is or should be.

Comment: In fact, section 4.7 of those notes suggest that finding a bijection to antichains of the poset of positive roots (i.e., to Dyck paths), may be an open problem...

Comment: Another reference which looks good: "Noncrossing partitions and representations of quivers," by Ingalls and Thomas. https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612219

Comment: Catalan numbers also occur in the enumeration of binary trees. Lutz Hille gives a natural bijection between tilting modules of $A_n$ and rooted binary trees with $n+1$ leaves. This bijection is explained in Section 9 of the following article by L. Hille: [On the volume of a tilting module](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02960868.pdf), Abh. Math. Sem. Univ. Hamburg **76** (2006), 261--277. There more or less natural bijections between Dyck paths and rooted binary trees, and a composition gives a bijection between tilting modules and Dyck paths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is more of an expansion of Sam's comments, but too long for a comment itself:

As pointed out by Sam in that Theorem 4.2.2.2, tilting modules of the linear type $A_n$ quiver are in natural correspondence to triangulations of a regular $(n+3)$-gon.

**Short answer:** Any bijection between triangulations and Dyck paths would work, and there are plenty. Everyone is "natural" in some respect and "unnatural" in others.

**Longer answer:** Triangulations of a polygon might be generalized to all finite type using either of the following:

- noncrossing partitions $NC$
- clusters $CL$
- Coxeter-sortable elements $CS$

and there is a uniform type-independent bijection between them.

On the other hand, Dyck paths might be generalized to antichains in the root poset of a finite crystallographic type $AC$.

One now has
$$|NC| = |CL| = |CS| = |AC|$$
and indeed many refinements of this identity hold (such as the one mentioned in Section 4.7).

The closest connection between the two that is known is (caution, self-reference!) the article [A uniform bijection between nonnesting and noncrossing partitions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.1277) jointly with Drew Armstrong and Hugh Thomas.

There is much more to say and more references to give, please look into (again caution!) [Cataland: Why the Fuss?](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.00710) for all needed notions and references.

Comment: Hmm, the user Dotsenko was really miffed when I used the title "Discriminating Deltas, Depressed Equations, and Fussy Catalan Numbers" in a 2012 post on my blog site that I mentioned on MO--I was denigrating a compatriot-- so I changed it to Generalized Catalan numbers.  Guess being established in academe grants some immunity to authoritarian nationalists.

Answer (score 3):

Start with a tilting module for the quiver $0\to 1\to 2\to ...\to n$.
Throw away the components with support at 0.
You get a support tilting module $T_1,...,T_k$ for $1\to 2\to ...\to n$.
Take, for each $T_i$, the part $\lambda_i$ equal to the top of $T_i$.
For example, every injective module gives $\lambda_i=1$.
Take the Young diagram of that partition.
The shadow of the Young diagram is the corresponding Dyck path of length $2n+2$.

Conversely, take a Dyck path of length $2n+2$. Then each down-step $D_i$ corresponds to a component $T_i$ of the corresponding tilting module.
The top of $T_i$ is at vertex $k$ where $k$ is the number of upsteps after $D_i$.
If $D_i$ goes from level $\ell+1$ to level $\ell$, the length of $T_i$ is equal to the number of upsteps since the last time the Dyck path went up to level $\ell$ (if none exists, $T_i$ is projective). For example, $T_{n+1}$ will be the projective injective $P_0$.